# Nginx Proxy Manager

Tags: docker, nginx-reverse-proxy, portainer

I need help pls!

I'm trying to setup Nginx Proxy Manager with my docker container. I've been following this tutorial from YouTube! [Putting it All Together - Docker, Docker-Compose, NGinx Proxy Manager, and Domain Routing - How To](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjJVmAI1Do4&t=1955s)

I created two subdomains in Hover.com exactly how the tutorial is doing.

[image: my domain names hover]

With minor changes... he uses "docks" and "manage-docks" I just replaced "docks" with "docker".

I have a server on Vultr where I installed my docker containers. In the tutorial, he used DigitalOcean droplet. Anyway, I'm using my Vultr's machine IP address to point to those two subdomains.

Navigating to docker.mydomain.com:81 does take me to the login page for Nginx Proxy Manager. But when I try to setup manage-docker.mydomain.com as a proxy host, the webpage doesn't even load for some reason.

[image: nignx proxy manager]

Here are my docker containers hosted on Portainer. As you can see, I'm trying to load up WordPress as my test dummy to see when things work. I only can see WordPress when I navigate to port :8080.

But the point of Nginx Proxy Manager is to get rid of the port, but so far not luck. Perhaps I'm missing something here? I hope you guys can help me out! Thanks!

I'm open to other software other than Nginx Proxy Manager if it makes it easier.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your container and NPM are on different docker networks, so you can't reference the container's IP. Instead, reference the gateway.

As an example, let's say I created an nginx container with `docker run 8080:80 -v ./html:/html -d nginx`. Then let's say I run this to find my IP address:

```bash
$ docker inspect nginx | grep -B1 IPAddress
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
```

You're setting `IPAddress` as the IP for WordPress in NPM, but you should be setting it to `Gateway`.

Note that you still need to set it to the host's port, not the port of WordPress inside the container. In my example, I would use these settings in NPM:
[image: Nginx Proxy Manager, IP set to 172.19.0.1, port is set to 8080]

Answer (score 0):

The url in npm should be external host ip + port that is redirected to the container, not the ip of the network inside docker.

Comment: To make this a good answer, please edit your answer and add the reference to it.